# Double Border using css, one should according to text and second should be 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, border

Need help in making 2 bordered heading, one should according to content provided in HTML and second should be `100%`, image is provided for reference.

[image]

I have tried it here

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e64e52;
}
h3:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
h3.display_inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>HOT DEALS</h3>

<h3 class="display_inline">HOT DEALS</h3>
```

Problem what I am facing is both are running parallel, if I made it `display: inline-block`, then it will remain according to content and if `display: block`, then both will be `100%`.

I am also open for JS solution :)

Help in the regards will highly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you see something you like on a site, you can inspect it in the browser to see the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Buddy, I have shared image of provided PSD which I need to develop, it's not screeshot of any website :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add additional element (e.g. span) inside your `h3` element, and style it separately like this:

```css
h3 > span{
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="display_inline">
  <span>HOT DEALS</span>
</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, your solution worked for me, but I made little change to make exactly what I want, created jsfiddle to share with you :)
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/86g10Lba/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Champs for the contribution,
I have found my solution, pasting code to help others.

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size:24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h3 > span {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e64e52;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h3:before {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="display_inline">
  <span>HOT DEALS</span>
</h3>

<h3 class="display_inline">
  <span>Inspiration &amp; News</span>
</h3>
```

Special thanks to @Chris for the solution, I have use his Idea to make it exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 0 0 12px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e64e52;
  display: inline-block;
}
span {position:relative;
padding: 0;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  height: 66px;
}
span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span><h3>HOT DEALS</h3></span>
```